# Как добавить свой метод в модуль Express() c использованием util?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Всем привет. Пытаюсь расширить модуль `express` и добавить туда свой метод.

В обще для этого использовался модуль `util`

Мой кусок кода:

```
var expressApplication = require('express');
var util = require('util');

function Application() {
    expressApplication.apply(this, arguments);
    this.handlers = {};
}
util.inherits(Application, expressApplication);

//добавление своего метода
Application.prototype.write = function(data) {
    console.log(data)
};
```

Потом вызываю его:

```
var app = new Application();

//проверяем наследование
console.log(app instanceof expressApplication); // true
console.log(Application.super_ === expressApplication); // true

//проверяем мои методы
console.log(app.write('test'));
```

Но когда я хочу вызвать методы самого экпресса - они мне не доступны, напрмер, так `console.log(app.use)` говорит ошибкой, что `app.use is not a function`

Подскажите пожалуйста, что не так, куда смотреть, чтобы исправить проблему? Как вариант, пробовался вместо `express` `koa`, там это отрабатывало.

Спасибо!